# How to select different email accounts for unique autoresponders at certain times of the week?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

I do IT for a local bakery.

The bakery is closed every Tuesday.

The owners want me to have their personal email addresses like bob@example.com and alice@example.com begin replying to every incoming email between 8pm Monday evening, and 10pm Tuesday evening with an automatic response along the lines of "We're closed Tuesdays, but will get back to you on Wednesday morning."

They have been disabling and enabling their autoresponder settings every week via Gmail settings... which isn't ideal. As sometimes they forget to toggle the autoresponder manually.

Is it possible for me to write a Google Script like this guy did:

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/90075/any-way-to-send-gmail-auto-response-at-certain-times-every-week/90089#90089

But a version of it that would say different responses for different email addresses under our google apps account?

I'm more than capable of writing up javascript and changing the code supplied in the stackexchange website... I'm just curious how I would go about enabling one set of autoresponders for the personal email accounts... and another set of autoresponders for the group email accounts.

As the autoresponder in the stackexchange website supplied above appears to only work with a single gmail address.

Answer (score 1):

I'll recommend to use Gmail API with Apps Script. Gmail API has option to Enable/Disable autoresponder.

The Script will run weekly using a time driven trigger which will update the auto responder First Day and last day of autoresponser for that week.

The trigger will have to be setup by both the accounts.